# When using `<svelte:component />`, is it possible to bind to custom props?

Tags: svelte-3

Suppose I have a very simple component, called `Simple.svelte`:

```
<script>
 let value;
</script>

Give me a value: <input type="text" bind:value={value} />
```

Now in a more complex component, I would like to use a `<svelte:component />` tag so that I generalize a pattern in my application (say, `Complex.svelte`):

```
<script>
import Simple from './Simple.svelte';
...

let templateComponent = Simple;
</script>

<svelte:component this={Simple}>
```

In this simple case, I'd like to bind to `Simple`'s `value` prop, is there any way I can do that?

Answer (score 0):

... just forgot to export the `item` prop on `Simple.svelte`:

```
<script>
 export let value;
</script>

Give me a value: <input type="text" bind:value={value} />
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.

```html
<script>
    import Simple from './Simple.svelte';
    let value;
</script>

<svelte:component this={Simple} bind:value/>
```

[Svelte REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/55b6c722c8f0464c9ffd0b79626cdb4b?version=3.28.0)